# Why GLES20.glGetAttribLocation returns different values for different devices?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I'm trying using OpenGL2.0 and create multiple cubes in 3D space, for android devices.

The code it runs perfectly in some devices, but not in others, and i don't know why... (All devices have OpenGL 2.0 supported, and have recent android versions [5.0 or 6.0])

I only know that the problem is in a -1 return value (see down)

```
int vertexShader = loadGLShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, R.raw.vertex);
int gridShader = loadGLShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, R.raw.grid_fragment);
int passthroughShader = loadGLShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, R.raw.fragment_color);

     cubeProgram1 = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
     GLES20.glAttachShader(cubeProgram1, vertexShader);
     GLES20.glAttachShader(cubeProgram1, passthroughShader);
     GLES20.glLinkProgram(cubeProgram1);
     GLES20.glUseProgram(cubeProgram1);

    cubePositionParam1 = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cubeProgram1, "a_Position");
    cubeNormalParam1 = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cubeProgram1, "a_Normal"); ----> Returns -1 Value
    cubeLightPosParam1 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(cubeProgram1, "u_LightPos");
    cubeModelParam1 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(cubeProgram1, "u_Model") cubeModelViewParam1 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(cubeProgram1, "u_MVMatrix");
    cubeModelViewProjectionParam1 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(cubeProgram1, "u_MVP");
```

....

```
 GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(cubeNormalParam1); ---> Returns -1 ...
```

The `cubeNormalParam1 = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cubeProgram1, "a_Normal");` returns value 2 in some devices, and -1 in others. Those who have -1 value, give error and doesn't run...

I'm trying see if the vertex_shader have errors but i can't see any problems...

```
uniform mat4 u_Model;
uniform mat4 u_MVP;
uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;
uniform vec3 u_LightPos;

attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Color;
attribute vec3 a_Normal;
attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;

varying vec4 v_Color;
varying vec3 v_Grid;
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;

void main() {
   v_Grid = vec3(u_Model * a_Position);


   vec3 modelViewVertex = vec3(u_MVMatrix * a_Position);
   vec3 modelViewNormal = vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0));

   float distance = length(u_LightPos - modelViewVertex);
   vec3 lightVector = normalize(u_LightPos - modelViewVertex);
   float diffuse = max(dot(modelViewNormal, lightVector), 0.5);

   diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.00001 * distance * distance)));
   v_Color = a_Color * diffuse;

   v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;

   gl_Position = u_MVP * a_Position;
}
```

Why this happen? Is the Hardware?

Any Solution to fix this?

---

To draw Cube i've this:

```
public void drawCube1() {
        cubeNumber = 1;

        GLES20.glUseProgram(cubeProgram1);
        GLES20.glUniform3fv(cubeLightPosParam1, 1, lightPosInEyeSpace, 0);
        // Set the Model in the shader, used to calculate lighting
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(cubeModelParam1, 1, false, modelCube, 0);
        // Set the ModelView in the shader, used to calculate lighting
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(cubeModelViewParam1, 1, false, modelView, 0);
        // Set the ModelViewProjection matrix in the shader.
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(cubeModelViewProjectionParam1, 1, false, modelViewProjection1, 0);
        // Set the position of the cube
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                cubePositionParam1, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, cubeVertices);
        // Set the normal positions of the cube, again for shading
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(cubeNormalParam1, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, cubeNormals);
        // Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        // Bind the texture to this unit.
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextura1);

        isLookingAtObject_Number(cubeNumber);

        // Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniform, 0);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinate, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, cubeTexture);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinate);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(cubePositionParam1);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(cubeNormalParam1);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        checkGLError("Drawing cube");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "different devices"? Different GPUs?

Comment: Different Android mobiles and VR Glasses, for example. 
It works in Glasses and some mobile phones, but in other mobiles doesn't work (S7 Edge, eg.). The GPU of all, support OpenGL 1.0, 2.0, 3.0.

Comment: The error is E/Menu: Drawing cube: glError 1281.

Comment: What does the associated fragment shader look like? If it doesn't use v_Color, then the implementation might feel at liberty to optimize away a whole load of calculations and even the a_Color and a_Normal attributes.

Comment: I was thinking about the same as @Columbo has mentioned here. If you are not using v_Color, the shader might be optimised and removes this attribute completely. So posting your fragment shader will also help

Comment: I'm using v_color to make the floor. 
The base of the code is TreasureHunt sample from Google Cardboard, and i'm modifying it to create my own project with multiple cubes with image textures. 
The problem is some devices can run it and others not.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Solution - multiplying with -1 value

```
 ... = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cubeProgram1, "a_Normal") * -1;
```

or

```
int value;
if( GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cubeProgram1, "a_Normal") < 0){
      value = -1;
}
else {
      value = 1;
}

... = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cubeProgram1, "a_Normal") * value;
```

Is not the best solution, but now it works.

Comment: This doesn't work - you're just hiding the error, not actually fixing it. You're turning a -1 (attribute not used) into a +1 (which is the binding location for a completely different attribute).

Comment: That's true, i'm hiding the error, and not fixing it.
But is the only solution i can find to make it works in the device, and it runs. 
I cannot find another solution for that :\

Comment: The fix is to stop calling `GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(cubeNormalParam1)` if the location returned from `GLES20.glGetAttribLocation()` is -1. Skip `GLES20.glVertexAttibPointer` too.

Answer (score 7):

```
Why GLES20.glGetAttribLocation returns different values for different devices?
```

... because different devices will have different hardware for setting up binding tables, and in some cases may completely optimize out redundant computations and repack the used attributes to save space. This is *exactly* why the API has a function call for getting binding locations on the device at runtime; if they were deterministic constants you wouldn't need a run-time call at all ...

The fact it returns -1 isn't an error; it is just showing that the attribute isn't needed (e.g. defined, but can optimized out because it doesn't contribute to the fragment pixel color), so this shouldn't cause any problems.

However it does mean that you can't safely assume (e.g.) that `a_Position` is always attribute 0, `a_Color` is always 1, `a_Normal` is always 2, etc. If you've hard coded that in your code then it's entirely possible you are uploading the wrong data to each attribute. You *must* query the binding locations to get the binding numbers to use (or use the shader-side static binding added in OpenGL ES 3.x).

Which actual GL API call is setting the GL error state?

Comment: I'm Using openGL2.0.

The error appear multiple times constantly is this one.

10301-10382/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt E/Menu: Drawing cube: glError 1281

Comment: ... yes, that tells you what the error is, but not which function call is causing it to be set. Without more info on exactly which function call is going wrong, it's impossible to help. Call your checkError function after every API call you make, and report the specific function which is setting the error - just reporting that "something has gone wrong" at the end is not particularly helpful for debugging ...

Comment: Thanks, 
I do that, the problem is, now the application run's and do not show anything, stay black .

I put the drawCube function , at update , in the question. Maybe the error is there... but i can't find it because the app run's and doesn't break.

Initialy, the error was here:
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(cubeNormalParam1); 
It was at, onSurfaceCreated(EGLConfig config){...
(and it returns -1 , that's why i think the problem was there)

I've changed it for the cubeDraw(), and now it runs (with Error 1281), but doesn't appear anything at the screen.

Comment: Can u Help me with this, @Isogen74 ?

Comment: No, because I'm not psychic and you've still not answered my last question. **Specifically which OpenGL ES call is setting the GL Error state?**

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1055
Process: (...).treasurehunt, PID: 31434
java.lang.RuntimeException: AQUI: glError 1281
|at  (...).Menu.checkGLError(Menu.java:270)

|at (...).Menu.onSurfaceCreated(Menu.java:559)
 |at (...).CardboardViewNativeImpl$RendererHelper .callOnSurfaceCreated(CardboardViewNativeImpl.java:772)
|at (...).CardboardViewNativeImpl$RendererHelper.onSurfaceCreated(CardboardViewNativeImpl.java:789)
| at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1617)
|at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1354)

Comment: Always break give error here: GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(cubeNormalParam1)

Comment: onSurfaceCreated @Isogen74

Comment: Good. Now go and read the OpenGL ES spec, look up what error code 1281 actually is in relation to glEnableVertexAttribArray. (Hint, that function only actually generates a single possible error). Then change your code not to do that.

Comment: Thx, I'm learning OpenGl, And in spec say _"If name is not an
active attribute, or if an error occurs, -1 will be returned"_

But my question is why it works in some devices and not in others... 
Two of them put value = 2 , other 2 put value = -1... and the same code...

I'm trying to debugging this... but i don't know how to solve it :\  @Isogen74

Comment: There is nothing to "fix" really - you're just doing one thing too many. Just stop calling `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` for attributes which return a -1 binding index. The -1 location indicates they are not used, so you don't need to call `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` at all.The reason some drivers return 2 and some return -1 is just down to some missing the optimization pass which removes unused ones.